# Click() works in IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, internet-explorer

I have code which is trivial but only works in IE not Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li#first').click();
});
```

I have also tried:

```
document.getElementById('first').click();
```

But that doesn't work either.

Is this an IE bug/feature or is `click()` not supported in the other browsers?

Responding to comments:

1. There is a single element with ID
   first, no more.
2. It is an onclick on the list element that expands the element and moves focus on a  Google Map element.
3. Running the code in patrick's response (adding another click event to the element) produced some interesting behaviour. When running `$('li#first').click()` only the new event fired, but physically clicking the element with the mouse fired both (new and original).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  How many elements on the page have the id "first"?

Comment: Works in IE but not in Firefox. Now that's something new

Comment: What other events are bound to the `<li>` element or it parents? How can you tell it was clicked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox does not support click().

Running `document.getElementById('first').click()` returns the following error `click is not a function`

So I added a snippet of code to add click() functionality to every element. [This code](http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?p=34595&postcount=5) was found after a painful series of google searches resulting in [this thread](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=59651).

The snippet is below and needs to be included just once on the page:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
   var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
   evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
   this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: jQuery's version of `click()` should have worked in Firefox. So this answer solves the problem you were having?

Comment: @patrick: Yeah it does. jQuery `click()` only worked when the event was added with jQuery.

Comment: Strange. I can fire a handler set up by an inline "onClick" in Firefox if I use jQuery's `.click()` function (jQuery 1.4.2). Glad you got it working, though.

Comment: I will edit the question to include the original code tomorrow.

Comment: I tested ur code in Firefox 3.0.19 but not in Firefox 16. Any solution for Firefox 16?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work in Firefox. Here's a full snippet that proves it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
--></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li#first')
            .click(function(){
                alert("I've been clicked: " + $(this).text());
            })
            .click();
    });
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li id="first">First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are right. Click works, but it was a bug caused by the situation - not click directly.

Answer (score 1):

try this
html

```
<a id="link" href="url">click here</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

also if this is somethng you don't want to do theb also try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#link")[0].click();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to go to the first link? You can't trigger a link's default action via a click.

But here's a workaround:

```
var link = jQuery("#first>a", this)
if(!link.onclick) window.open(link.href, link.target || "_self")
else jQuery(link).click()
```

Source: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-a-0-click-not-working

Comment: It is an onclick on the list element that expands the element and moves focus on a Google Map element.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does support the .click() JQuery function. I had the same problem, until I specified the tag name in my selector. Essentially, I had something like this:

```
<a id="vidLeftArrow" blah blah blah>...</a>
$("#vidLeftArrow").click(function () {
   //Do something
});
```

Which didn't work. I had to change the javascript to this:

```
<a id="vidLeftArrow" blah blah blah>...</a>
$("a#vidLeftArrow").click(function () {
   //Do something
});
```