# Javascript: click() not navigating to the link in Firefox 2

Tags: javascript, firefox2

While following the answer here: [Click() works in IE but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812411/click-works-in-ie-but-not-firefox)

I no longer get the "click is not a function message" error message and indeed get the "Clicked" alert message, however the browser does not navigate to the page. I tried it on the latest version of firefox and it navigates, just not happening in Firefox 2.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {var evt = 
this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, 
this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, 
null);this.dispatchEvent(evt);};

document.onclick= function(event) { if (event===undefined) event= window.event; var target= 
'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; alert("clicked");};

document.getElementById("anId").click();

document.onclick= function(event) { if (event===undefined) event= window.event; var target= 
'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; alert("clicked");};
```

Comment: I don't use ff2 browser but the library I use, incorporates xulrunner from FF2.

Comment: Check these urls, I hope they help you :) http://forums.asp.net/t/1321236.aspx/1 and http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/fix-firefox-click-event-issue

Comment: provide html of your anchor link and also check in firebug console .is there any error on click

Comment: yeah ive looked at those and it seems like theres just no way to go about doing this in such an old ff engine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById("anId").onclick();` it will work on all the browsers. `click();` works only on IE.

Comment: it means there's some other bug. Either no element exists with this `id` or that element doesn't have `onclick` attribute defined.

Comment: manually inject onclick attribute to the element with empty value?

Comment: this method requires the element to have onclick attribute, I need a solution that will generate a click event on any element.

Comment: like a scenario I would ave problem with is, if you were to do href.location = "somewhere"; onclick(), however, I don't want to override the default onclick behavior set by the web application. What I am looking for is a way to emulate mouse click behavior using javascript in FF2....there seems to be no other way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8433/discussion-between-tsf-and-kim-jong-woo)

Comment: are you trying to listen an onclick event on a element that doesn't expect to have onclick event?

Answer (score 1):

I think since FF2 is too old and not sure whether it supports the click prototype, better way would be to something like this

html

```
<a id="link" href="url">click here</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

also if this is somethng you don't want to do theb also try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#link")[0].click();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin and use it's `.click()` event.

You can see more details **[here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)**.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812411/click-works-in-ie-but-not-firefox).

Here's what you're to use to add the functionality...

```
HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
   var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
   evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
   this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JQuery...
http://api.jquery.com/click/
maybe you are trying to listen on an html element that does not expect to  accept onClick event. `click()` only works in IE. and if you gonna try Jquery event listener `click`, **you can cover all the problems in all major browsers**