# Why click event working fine in Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

This is a simple scenario, the click event is working fine in Firefox but not IE. Let's go in the detail. I have a button which is like below:

```
<h:form id="theForm">
  <h:commandLink id="theButton" styleClass="button" action="#{theBean.doWork}"/>
</h:form>
```

When I try to invoke the click event of the button from JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('theForm:theButton').click();
```

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812411/click-works-in-ie-but-not-firefox), I am required to put the code below like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
    var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
```

But when I have this code in my JavaScript, it really work in Firefox, but not in IE anymore. May I know how can I make it work on both IE and Firefox?

Comment: I'd recommend to use jQuery to bind events - it takes care about cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: i.e not like when you skip `;` add  it to the end of function declaration (last string here)

Comment: @brains911 Are you referring to the main `.prototype.click` part or what?

Comment: @Ian I misunderstood the question.  Deleted comment to avoid causing confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if(!HTMLElement){
var HTMLElement = Element;
}
HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
    var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

This should work for IE>=8, which uses `Element` to provide the same interface `HTMLElement` does in other browsers.

Comment: I tested this code in Firefox 16, it is not working. But Firefox 3.0.19 doesn't work. Any solution for Firefox 16?

Comment: @huahsin68 So it isn't working in either one? Because I'm using 16 and this works. http://jsfiddle.net/xacns/

Comment: I have 2 machines here, so I tested on both version. It is not working in Firefox 16.0.2, but working in Firefox 3.0.19.

Comment: @huahsin68 That is very strange, because I'm using 16.0.2, and when I open that fiddle I get an alert. Don't you?

Comment: yes, the alert is working but the `theBean.doWork`, click event din't get trigger.

Comment: @huahsin68 What is `theBean.doWork`? This is not mentioned anywhere in your question. Your question was about adding a method to trigger click events, and I have provided a way to do this.

Comment: Yah, you got the point. I though by adding you solution into my code, I can trigger the `doWork` because it is working fine in IE, thus I am making the assumtion that by activating the click event, the `doWork` will get trigger. Anyhow, the question has been resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using jQuery:

```
$("#theButton").click(function() {alert("Handler for .click() called.");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed semicolon - IE not like that

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
    var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  };
```

and yes, be sure to have HTMLElement patched

`var HTMLElement =HTMLElement===undefined?Element:HTMLElement;`

Comment: Are you actually sure about that? This is no different from skipping the semicolon at the end of other lines. I don't remember IE being that strict - browsers attempt to fill it in automatically.

Comment: And you should give credit to @Asad who actually proposed the `HTMLElement` patch

Comment: i not sure if it last line -  `<script>` not closed, but after declaring var you should close it with ;

Comment: Yes, you **should**, but you don't have to. And I don't think IE is complaining about something like that. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: @lan http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Dj7ak/ click jslint here, i don't know how it in case of last line, but in case of not last line, ie fail without semicolon

Comment: Really? jslint is not some almighty javascript god, and javascript doesn't have the most strict semantics.

Comment: do you have IE ?  i don't but i got complains from IE users several times when ; was skipped.

Comment: @eicto When I started learning javascript I ran all my snippets in IE, and I nearly always forgot my semi colons. Trust me, it doesn't break your code.

Comment: @Asad when I got the complains about IE test fail in most cases it was missing semicolon.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of IE you used...maybe 5.5? Shouldn't matter, they aren't required and wouldn't break. Now, it is important to use them when you are using `()` around inline code, as it can be interpreted as a function call.

Comment: I can't test now, as i have no IE near me, but i think it was at least IE7 last time

Comment: Well I highly doubt simply putting a semicolon in fixed your problem. Unless you didn't include one for a `do/while` loop (which requires one), or something messy with `return` statements that can be troublesome if you don't use them correctly. Something like a variable declaration is the lease of anyone's worries when it comes to semicolons (but again, it depends on what comes before and after the line)