# How to trigger hidden JSF commandLink in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, facelets, managed-bean

I have a similar question on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206421/why-click-event-working-fine-in-firefox-but-not-ie) where I have a JavaScript function which will trigger the click event of a hidden `commandLink`. And the hidden command will fire the action in Java Bean. This code is working fine in IE, but not in Firefox. Is there any clue on this issue?

**JavaScript**

```
<h:outputScript target="head">
    HTMLElement.prototype.click = function() {
    var evt = this.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  function triggerHiddenEvent() {
    alert("triggerHiddenEvent is trigger");
    document.getElementById("theForm:hiddenCommand").click();
  }
</h:outputScript>
```

**XHTML**

```
<h:form id="theForm">
  <h:commandLink id="tri_HiddenEvent" value="Trigger Hidden Event" onclick="triggerHiddenEvent"/>

  <p style="display:none">
    <h:commandLink id="hiddenCommand" styleClass="button" action="#{helloBean.doHiddenCommand}"/>
  </p>
  ...
```

**The Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean implements Serializable {
  public String doHiddenCommand() {
    System.out.println("doHiddenCommand is called");
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: how about `onclick="triggerHiddenEvent()"` adding `()` ?

Comment: the onclick event will trigger the JavaScript function `triggerHiddenEvent()`.

Comment: what about `onclick="triggerHiddenEvent(); return false;"` ?

Comment: Perfect!! It works!! Why? What the return false trying to do? Can you update this issue in your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`onclick="triggerHiddenEvent"`

into

`onclick="triggerHiddenEvent(); return false;"`

you need to add the `return false;` snippet in order to stop the page from submitting/reloading...

> h:commadLink Tag:
>
> This tag generates HTML’s  `<a href` link tag and some JavaScript
>   functions which make the link to act as a submit button.
>   To prevent page submission, you have to explicitly add simple `return false;` to
>   your onclick function

[Difference Between h:commandButton , h:commandLink and h:outputLink in JSF](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/09/07/difference-between-hcommandbutton-hcommandlink-and-houtputlink-in-jsf/)

Comment: I had try your solution and it behave the same. I just found out that if I put a breakpoint at `document.getElementById("theForm:hiddenCommand").click();` in firebug, it actually will execute the `doHiddenCommand()`. When I remove the breakpoint, it doesn't execute anymore. I am just so curious whether I need to put some delay or `sleep(1000)` when executing the click event from JavaScript in order to make it work?

Comment: how to you call the `triggerHiddenEvent()` ?