# Primefaces Dialog Framework -- dialogReturn event from menuitem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a primefaces `p:datatable` in `Table.xhtml` and have a `p:commandbutton` on the same page which I am using to open a dialog using dialog framework. The content related to dialog is in `Dialog.xhtml`. I am using a single backing bean named `TableDialog.java` for both `Table.xhtml` and `Dialog.xhtml`. When the dialog is closed, the values in the `p:datatable` are updated accordingly using the

```
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{tableDialog.test}" update = ":form:colors"  />
```

The `Table.xhtml`  is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Table</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h:form id="form">  
     <p:dataTable id="colors" var="col" value="#{tableDialog.resourceList}" rowKey="#{col}"  
                     selection="#{tableDialog.selected}" selectionMode="single">  
     <p:column headerText="Model">  
                #{col}  
            </p:column>  
     <f:facet name="footer">  
                <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="Add" icon="ui-icon-search" 
                actionListener="#{tableDialog.updateValue}"    > 
       <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{tableDialog.test}" update = ":form:colors" onclick="this.form.submit()" />  
                        </p:commandButton> 
            </f:facet>  
    </p:dataTable>  
        <p:contextMenu for="colors">
            <p:menuitem  value="Add" actionListener="#{tableDialog.updateValue}"  update=" :form:colors   "  >
                 
                </p:menuitem>
                </p:contextMenu>
    </h:form> 
   </h:body>
    </html>
```

and here is the Dialog.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Dialog</title>
</h:head>

    <h:body>  
        <h:form>
          <h:panelGrid id="updateValuePanel" columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px">  
          <h:outputLabel value="Attribute Value "  />
           <p:inputText id="attributeValue" value="#{tableDialog.attributeValue}" required="true" />
        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton id="saveValue" value="Submit" actionListener="#{tableDialog.saveValue}" 
                />  
                <p:commandButton id="cancelValue" value="Cancel "
                action="#{tableDialog.cancelValue}"
                />
        <p:defaultCommand target="saveValue" />
              </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

the TableDialog.java contains the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;



@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableDialog {   
    
    public ArrayList<String> resourceList=new ArrayList<String>();
    
private String selected;
String attributeValue = null;

public  TableDialog(){
    this.resourceList.add("Black");
    this.resourceList.add("White");
    
}
public void updateValue(){
    System.out.println("update  value");
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("dynamic", true);
    options.put("height", 100);
    options.put("width", 300);
    options.put("contentHeight", 100);
    options.put("contentWidth", 250);
    
    context.openDialog("Dialog", options, null);
    
    
}
public void test(){
    System.out.println("test");
    
}

public void  cancelValue(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    context.closeDialog(this.attributeValue);
    
    System.out.println("cancel update resource attribute value");
    this.attributeValue = null;
    System.out.println("this.attributevalue  = " + this.attributeValue);
      
}

public void  saveValue(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    if (this.attributeValue == null) 
    {
         System.out.println("No value");
           context.execute("noValueDialog.show()"); 
           
          return;
          
    }
    
    System.out.println("this.attributevalue = " + this.attributeValue);
        this.resourceList.add(this.attributeValue);
        this.attributeValue = null;
        context.update("form:resourceAttributeValueDataTable");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:resourceAttributeValueDataTable");
        
    context.closeDialog(this.attributeValue); 
    System.out.println("after hidden button execute " );
        
}

public String getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(String selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
public ArrayList<String> getResourceList() {
    return resourceList;
}
public void setResourceList(ArrayList<String> resourceList) {
    this.resourceList = resourceList;
}
public String getAttributeValue() {
    return attributeValue;
}
public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
    this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
}


}
```

**everything is working fine.**

**My problem is:**

I want to use `p:contextMenu` for opening the dialog. `p:menuitem` opens the dialog correctly but I am unable to update the `p:dataTable` after the dialog is closed. As the dialog framework only supports `p:commandButton` or `p:commandLink` I can't use

```
<p:ajax event="dialogReturn" />
```

inside `p:menuitem`. Searching for a work around on the internet I found the solution at http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=32131. It says

> "For now, you can do the following to workaround :
>
> 1. Remove `p:ajax` from `menuitem`
> 2. Add `p:commandbutton` xhtml and add id="..." and style="display:none"
> 3. Add onclick="..." to menuitem to use javascript to trigger the click() event of the >commandbutton, and reference the button where name should be "formID:buttonID"."

I am a newbie in java, primefaces and ajax and know nothing about javascript and jquery. So I am unable to figure out what exactly to write inside  onclick="........"

```
<p:menuitem  value="Add" actionListener="#{tableDialog.updateValue}" 
            update=" :form:colors   "  onclick="........" >
```

so that whenever I select a menu item the hidden button is executed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution on [How to trigger hidden JSF commandLink in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219391/how-to-trigger-hidden-jsf-commandlink-in-javascript)

The updated version of Table.xhtml contains

```
  <h:form id="form">  

        <p:dataTable id="colors" var="col" value="#{tableDialog.resourceList}" rowKey="#{col}"  
                     selection="#{tableDialog.selected}" selectionMode="single">  


            <p:column headerText="Model">  
                #{col}  
            </p:column>  




        </p:dataTable>  
        <p:contextMenu for="colors">
                <p:menuitem  value="Add"  onclick="triggerHiddenEvent(); return false;"
                update=" :form:colors   "  >


                </p:menuitem>
                </p:contextMenu>



       <p:commandButton id="hiddenCommand" styleClass="button"  action="#{tableDialog.updateValue}"  style="display:none">
         <p:ajax event="dialogReturn"  update = ":form:colors"  />  

        </p:commandButton>

        <h:outputScript >

      function triggerHiddenEvent() {
        document.getElementById("form:hiddenCommand").click();
      }
    </h:outputScript>

    </h:form>
```