# Returns binary file and an other object with C# IHttpActionResult

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, binaryfiles

I've learned how to returns binary files from C# Web Api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005841/what-is-wrong-with-my-download-of-a-zip-file-from-an-asp-apicontroller-with-angu).

Now I want to do the same thing with a *IHttpActionResult*. I've found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768596/why-is-my-file-not-being-returned-by-a-get-request-from-my-web-api-function).

But what if I'd like to return an other object with the file ? I can return objects with [*Ok*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Ok%60%601(%60%600)) or [*Content*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.content(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ApiController.Content%60%601(System.Net.HttpStatusCode,%60%600)) functions but is it possible to do both at the same time ?

I got the idea of returning an object containing a C# byte array (resulting from [*File.ReadAllBytes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)) and create the Blob in JS from it. But the C# byte array becomes a string in JS and I have to convert it to a byte array again. Beyond the fact that it does not seems to be a very robust solution the codes I've found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729405/how-to-convert-utf8-string-to-byte-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195865/converting-byte-array-to-string-in-javascript)) to achieve this do not work for me.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use the http headers.